Meaning of water droplets symbol on mini split?
Not sure what this symbol means on the right - “water droplets down lines” is the best I can describe it.
You can see it on the middle right of the display on page 19 here, but it does not explain it.
https://marsdelivers.com/wps/wcm/connect/04368dc4-a881-4d08-ab12-bb4ec244c5e3/VMH_09-24SC_service+manual_+Inverter+Mini-Split_3-28-12.pdf?MOD=AJPERES&CONVERT_TO=url&CACHEID=04368dc4-a881-4d08-ab12-bb4ec244c5e3

The last page of the manual has a phone number.  You could call the manufacturer and ask that question for an exact answer.

Good idea. I tried that. The guy was not super confident since apparently this is an older model (and it seems the company has changed hands to what is now the current company) but best he could tell it is the defrost mode like @Ecnerwal said in his answer.

Virtually certain that's indicating defrost mode in operation.
The alternative is that it's an unusual symbol for dehumidify mode (page 32) (which I missed it having as most that I've met call it dry mode and that's what I searched for) and that would presumably be easy to see if it cycles through fan, cool, heat, auto, and that symbol as you change modes.

Interesting - as obvious as this may be, what would cause that? I’m surprised because I’ve had it set to a temperature pretty close to the outside just to have the air moving some, and temperatures have been quite mild

Read from page 29-30.

Thanks. It does call its dehumidify mode dry mode - at least, that is how it is labeled on the corresponding remote. I tried calling the manufacturer based on a comment on my question and their best guess (really all they had, the tech was not very confident) was that your first answer is correct and that it is defrost mode.

Smells like "US" Company, but product arrives upriver in a container from China given the graphic-only nature of the display, and the lack of product knowledge by support leans that way too. I don't see the remote in the manual at all...
